# Flutter WebView is not updating URL correctly for some sites

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, wkwebview

I am using the `flutter_webView` in my app like this:

```
  WebView(
    initialUrl: 'https://www.mediamarkt.de/',
    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
    onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
      _controller = webViewController;
    },
    onPageStarted: (String url) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
    },
    onPageFinished: (String url) {
      setState(() {
        _currentUrl = url;
        _isLoading = false;
        print('onagePageFinished: $_currentUrl');
      });
    },
  ),
```

**Problem:**

As you can see, I am updating the `url` everytime `onPageFinished` is called. That works for most of the time. However when navigating *https://www.mediamarkt.de/* nothing is called. The URL is always the same.

What am I missing here? Let me know if you need any more information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the solution was rather simple:

```
final String? url = await _controller.currentUrl();
```

not quite sure why `onPageFinished` is not always refreshing correctly but with the above code everything is working just as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue my url is not refreshing you should see 2 boxes not one.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double heights = 800;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WebViewController? _webviewController;

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: [],
        ),
        body: RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: () {
            return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
              _webviewController!.reload();
            });
          },
          child: Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: heights,
                    child: WebView(
                      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                      initialUrl:
                          "https://christfamilychurchnashville.org/acalendar/",
                      onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                        _webviewController = webViewController;
                      },
                      onPageFinished: (content) async {
                        var _heights = double.parse(await _webviewController!
                            .evaluateJavascript(
                                "document.documentElement.scrollHeight"));
                        heights = _heights;

                        // setState(() {});
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```